# Shapes not matching in numpy.convolve

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

Error message:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (603) (613)
```

What should I do?
Do both of the list need to be the same length?
Or should I zero-pad it?

Here's my code:

```
def gaussian_smooth1(img, sigma): 
    '''
    Do gaussian smoothing with sigma.
    Returns the smoothed image.
    '''
    result = np.zeros_like(img)

    #get the filter
    filter = gaussian_filter(sigma)

    #get the height and width of img
    width = len(img[0])
    height = len(img)

    #smooth every color-channel
    for c in range(3):
        #smooth the 2D image img[:,:,c]
        #tip: make use of numpy.convolve
        for x in range(height):
            result[x,:,c] = np.convolve(filter,img[x,:,c])
        for y in range(width):
            result[:,y,c] = np.convolve(filter,img[:,y,c])
    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because you do not specify the right `mode`.
Read it up in the documentation:
[numpy.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)

The default for *numpy.convolve* is `mode='full'`.

> This returns the convolution at each point of overlap, with an output
>   shape of (N+M-1,).

`N` is the size of the input array, `M` is the size of the filter. So the output is larger than the input.

Instead you want to use `np.convolve(filter,img[...],mode='same')`.

Also have a look at 
[scipy.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html) which allows 2D convolution using the FFT.